# How to re-create vanilla field configuration strings programmatically for any field?

Tags: 7, entities, database

After a D7 update and migration of fields, most of our problems with converted fields result from invalid or incompatible field settings. Field settings are stored in the
`field_config_instance.data` column in the database as serialized php objects.

How can I, for any given field instance, generate a fresh field configuration string, as if the field was just created in D7, while leaving the already stored field data intact?

My manual approach seems to work but is very cumbersome:

- create a new content type
- add an existing field to the new content type, generating new settings string
- search the new and old field in the database
- using sql: replacing the string in the data column of the old field (with the same name) with the new data content.

There must be a way to automate this a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you will need a combination of [field_update_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_field/7) and [field_create_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7).

During `field_create_field()`, the settings are loaded from the default field definition as each field has defined in its own [hook_field_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7).

```
$field['settings'] += field_info_field_settings($field['type']);
```

What you are looking for is to apply this logic to `field_update_field()`.

Basically you will need to load all fields:

```
$fields = field_info_fields();
```

Optionally limit the fields to your selection:

```
foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'some type') {} // Filter by type
  if ($field_name == 'some name') {} // Filter by name
}
```

And update the fields:

```
$field['settings'] = field_info_field_settings($field['type']);
field_update_field($field);
```

So I guess it should look something like this:

```
$fields = field_info_fields();
foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field) {
  if ($field['type'] == 'some type') {
    $field['settings'] = field_info_field_settings($field['type']);
    field_update_field($field);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think its very good information. I have run the suggested script and am printing the field settings before and after for all fields, however, the field settings appear unchanged whenever I run the script. Looking into the code of field_update_field. this line: `$field['settings'] += $prior_field['settings'];` computes the union of new and old settings. If I am not mistaken, this will always guarantee I will not loose any settings. In my case I need to remove the full settings record unfortunately, or at least remove some keys.

Comment: That is why I changed it into a regular = in the final snippet ;)

Comment: I see, but what I am saying is that field_update_field contains the same logic inside (using +=), so I will never be able to delete anything from the settings when using this function, if I am correct. So whenever a field is missing in the new settings but present in the old settings, field_update_field will keep the old settings.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but that union will make sure all non-defined values in the settings array will be set with the values of the previous field. Since we redefine the whole settings array with its defaults, I assumed it should be good. If the result is not as expected you can place the contents of the complete `field_update_field()` function in the snippet above and remove the union.

Comment: It might also be that modules implement `hook_field_update_forbid`. So you could attempt to bypass that as well.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to modify the functions to circumvent all protection mechanisms.